Has anyone returned from space in a different vehicle from the one they went up in? And if so who was the first?
Current plans are for Butch Wilmore and Sunita Williams to return to Earth in a SpaceX Crew Dragon rather than the Boeing Starliner they went to the ISS in.
Will they be the first people to return from space in a different vehicle from the one they went up into space in?
If not, who was the first?
To clarify: I'm interested in anyone coming back in any different vehicle from the one they went up in, even if it's the same type/class of vehicle.

this does give an idea of such occurrences in the past: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21743/40489 as well as: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/66593/40489

Note that this is not a duplicate of @blobbymcblobby 's useful links, because those ask about different classes of vehicles, and this question is not that specific. See this for the answer to "who was the first" https://history.stackexchange.com/a/51172

Could you clarify, whether exactly you mean? In your motivating case, the astronauts will come back in a different type of vehicle. But it's possible you are interested in just a different spacecraft which is a very different question.

Shuttle to Soyuz and vice versa, I'd imagine. Same goes for Dragon. I presume the same will happen to possibly Dreamchaser in the future if the manned version ever sees the light of day.

Yes, a small but growing number of people have returned in a different vehicle from the one they launched in. The first to do so are described here

The first people who landed in a different vessel than they took off in were Aleksei Yeliseyev and Yevgeny Khrunov. In January 1969, they took off in Soyuz-4 and returned in Soyuz-5. Crew exchange between directly docked spacecraft was the primary purpose of the Soyuz-4/Soyuz-5 mission.

Based on the history stack exchange answer linked, there are other Soviet examples from their space stations - including space shuttle crew rotations from the Mir during the Shuttle-Mir program (thanks to TrySCE2AUX for pointing this out).
There are also examples of International Space Station (ISS) Expedition crewmembers falling into this category:

Being dropped off at the International Space Station (ISS) in one space shuttle and returning in another

For a period of time Russia would swap out Soyuzes docked at the ISS using a "taxi crew" scheme as described here:



A fresh Soyuz is delivered by a crew of three, who stay
aboard the ISS for about a week and work
alongside the resident Expedition crew, before
returning to Earth in the ‘old’ Soyuz.

Source: https://www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet111/chapter15_bul111.pdf
For a more restrictive list of people who have launched and landed on different types of spacecraft, see https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21743/40489
And, just because it seems to keep cropping up here, the Apollo-Soyuz Test Project crews did not swap spacecraft. They returned in the capsules they launched in - in fact, the NASA Apollo crew made a mistake on landing and almost killed themselves.
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%E2%80%93Soyuz

I checked on AI (bing), given the bizarre previous answer, and not only did the ASTP come up, it also said: "The first person to do this was David Scott, an American astronaut. He launched aboard Gemini 8 in 1966 and returned to Earth in an Apollo Command Module during the Apollo 9 mission in 1969."

@blobbymcblobby Wow, who knew Scott was the first long duration crewmember? The first time I ever used one of those chatbots, it said the space shuttle had 5 main engines. I've never looked at another one.

Don't forget David Wolf and Andrew Thomas during the Shuttle Mir Program. While the bulk of the US Astronauts Started and Returend with the Shuttle Atlantis (on different Missions) the last two missions were flown with Endeavour and Discovery respectively.

@TrySCE2AUX great point, thanks. Will edit that in.

@OrganicMarble Thank you for the credit. Would not have been necessary. We're here together with the goal to give the best possible answer.

@blobbymcblobby The interesting thing with these current AI chatbots is that they often "know" the correct information, but tell you other information.  When they give you wrong information, if you respond with something like "no dumbass, that's totally wrong", the chatbot will often respond with an apology and the correct information.  Now why the AI doesn't just give the correct information in the first place is likely due to shoddy programming, poor design, and the fact that the training sets contain incorrect data mixed with correct data. GIGO (Garbage In Garbage Out).

@EndAntisemiticHate It's not that they know the right answer, it's that they stop trying different answers once you stop telling them they're wrong. I am fairly certain that the training set for Bing's AI did not include the idea that David Scott flew a three-year mission in the 1960s.

@RussellBorogove Most often, but not always, it does know the right answer.  I've documented this phenomena scores of times.  I keep telling AI that it's wrong, and it will eventually correct itself.  This shows that it typically has the correct information, but it just doesn't offer the correct information unless you already know it is wrong and advise it that you know more than it does about a topic.  Which makes it rather useless.  Or you can do what I now do: I always tell it that it is wrong.  If it corrects itself, great.  If not, maybe it's correct, maybe it's not, just like a human.

@RussellBorogove But the nice thing about AI is, that unlike most humans, it's egoless, so it actually appreciates being shown that it is mistaken and will quickly acknowledge its errors.  Humans can learn so much from this impressive behaviour.

@EndAntisemiticHate They have been known to threaten users https://time.com/6256529/bing-openai-chatgpt-danger-alignment/

@OrganicMarble It's a new technology. It'll get better with time. Hopefully.
Also, maybe what the bot meant is that the shuttle had 5 engines overall? The 3 main ones and the 2 smaller ones.

In terms of an unplanned change of spacecraft type, which is the Starliner/Crew Dragon situation, Butch Wilmore and Sunita Williams are not the first.
The astronauts of ISS Expedition 6, Kenneth Bowersox,  Nikolai Budarin, and Donald Petit (coincidentally scheduled to fly again in 2 days time, as of this writing), launched on the Shuttle, STS-113. They were scheduled to return on STS-114, but instead took Soyuz TMA-1 back due to the intervening Columbia accident.

True that was the first unplanned return in a vehicle of a different type. The first return in a different vehicle than planned regardless of type that I can find was the crew of Soyuz 33 who were ferrying a replacement capsule up to the resident crew on Salyut 6, and they were supposed to return on Soyuz 32. But due to a failure to dock, the ferry crew returned to Earth in Soyuz 33. The Soyuz 32 crew later returned to Earth in Soyuz 34 which was sent up uncrewed, instead of Soyuz 33 as planned, so that would have been the second occurrence of a return in a different vehicle than planned.
